# Convert a Queryset object to a model instance

Tags: django

I have two models as following:

```
class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Book(models.Model):
    genre= models.ForeignKey(Genre, related_name="book",  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

```
def save_book(book_list):
    #book_list is a list of dict: [{'name': 'xxx', 'genre': 'xxx'}, {...}]
    for book in book_list:
        book_genre = book['genre']
        genre= Genre.objects.get(name=book_genre )
        book = {'name': book['name'],
                'genre': genre}
        new_book = Book(**book)
        new_book.save()
```

In the code above, instead of hitting the database with each `Genre.objects.get(name=book_genre )`, I want to use `Genre.objects.all()` to get all of them at once. However, this code:

```
def save_book(book_list):
    #book_list is a list of dict: [{'name': 'xxx', 'genre': 'xxx'}, {...}]
    genres= Genre.objects.all()
    for book in book_list:
        book_genre = book['genre']
        genre= genres.filter(name=book_genre)
        book = {'name': book['name'],
                'genre': genre}
        new_book = Book(**book)
        new_book.save()
```

gives the error

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "<QuerySet [Genre:]>": "Book.genre" must be a "Genre" instance.
```

How do I convert a member of the queryset to a model instance to be assign along foreign key as above?

Comment: Since you use `.filter(..)` these will still make requests to the database: one for each `.filter(..)`.

Comment: I see. How do I keep the queryset in memory and avoid hitting the database multiple times, in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use [**`.filter(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) these will still make requests to the database: one for each `.filter(…)`.

What you can do is make a dictionary that maps the names on the `Genre`s:

```
def save_book(book_list):
    #book_list is a list of dict: [{'name': 'xxx', 'genre': 'xxx'}, {...}]
    genre_names = [b['genre'] for b in book_list]
    genres= {g.name: g for g in Genre.objects.filter(name__in=genre_names) }
    books = [
        Book(name=book['name'], genre=genres[book['genre']])
        for book in book_list
    ]
    Book.objects.bulk_create(books)
```

We thus first construct a dictionary for all the genres we need, and then make `Book` instances. We use [**`.bulk_create(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) to create records in a single query.